# Error code when entering formula into vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working formula in excel and I am trying to put it into a macro to add the formula to column A. However I get a Expected end of statement error message at "Payer ID is not set up".

```
Worksheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Range("B2:B & LastRow").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF('payorTab'! A:A, B2)>0, "", "PayerID is not set up")"
End Sub
```

For the macro to insert the formula into the column A.

Comment: Try changing: `Range("B2:B & LastRow")` to `Range("B2:B" & LastRow)`. (Move the quotation marks.

Comment: Side note to what @user3561813 eludes to. You are concatenating a string and a `Long` (hopefully), so your quotation marks need to wrap the string part. The `&` is the symbol used to concatenate strings in VBA.

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting a syntax error messge

Comment: You need to Wrap your `""` in double quotes within the Formula `""""`

Comment: still getting a syntax error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Worksheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF('payorTab'!A:A,B2)>0, """", ""PayerID is not set up"")"
```

Comment: Getting run-time error '1004', application defined or object defined error

Comment: Check the content of lastrow. It cannot be 0 or emtpy

Comment: I've checked and last row is neither of those

Comment: check if payorTab sheet exists.

Comment: checked, and it exists

Comment: Within the spreadsheet I have 6 tabs, one is "1099-Misc_Form_template" and another is "PayorTab"

Comment: Can you paste your formula for `LastRow` and also which datatype are you using to define it? Also, can you let us know what is the value of your `LastRow`? E.g. you can add the following to your VBA code to check it out: `Debug.Print LastRow`

Comment: I Cannot reproduce your problem. note that your formula results in a circular reference. ( you put in  B2 a formula which takes one of its input in B2) to check the result formula you can replace the = character by ' , run the macro and check the content of column B:B, if formula looks ok, replace the ' sign by = sign and execute the formula and verify if it is ok.